# How can we scrape pop-up login dialogboxes?

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, popup

I am doing some scraping (with BeautifulSoup) for a script that will check some times on some pages on a website,
and at some point the website has a "protected" areea that is only accessible by username and passwd
Can you please give me some ideas of how can i "POST" the username and password so i can authenticate and continue scraping?(username and password are known)

i tried :

```
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
requests.get("url",auth=HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\username','password'))
```

- Not working - 401

..................................................................

then i swithched to :

`http(s)://(username):(password)@(url)`

- Not Working - 401

..................................................................

then i gave a try by :

```
with requests.Session() as s:
     s.post("url", data = {
            'dbconnect': 'y',
            'entryPoint': 1001,
            'numblogon': 0,
            'password': "password",
            'username': "username",
        })
        restricted_value = 30
```

- same answer for all of them  - 401

..................................................................

This is the type of poup dialog box that i need to authenticate trough :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.post(url, auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth("User", "Pass"))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        print(soup.prettify())


main("Your Url")
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer, but unfortunately the return answer is the same - 401...

Comment: @tiberiusz in that case, include the headers and give it a try. also do you have a live version so we can debug ?